# Android - SharedPreferences Error related to Context

Tags: java, android

I have a question about `SharedPreferences`. I have implemented them in a class called `HashM.java`. Starts something like this:

```
public void getPrefs (Context BaseContext) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseContext);
```

I am trying to call it in my click listener this way:

```
HashM hash = new HashM();
hash.getPrefs();
```

But, I get an error:

```
getPrefs (Context) in HashM cannot be applied
```

Can someone point me to how I can fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPrefs(Context)` expects context as a parameter. You need to pass the activity context inside it.

You can do it like this

```
HashM hash = new HashM();
hash.getPrefs(MyActivity.this); // MyActivity is the activity where you are putting this code
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HashM class has more methods which need a specified context, consider to make a constructor for this class with a Context parameter, and assign it to a variable, like this:

```
class HashM
Context mContext;

public HashM  (Context context) {
mContext = context;
}

public void getPrefs () {
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

And make a reference as

```
HashM hashM = new HashM(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Rohit5k2's answer, you can also use

```
HashM hash = new HashM(); 
hash.getPrefs(getActivity());
```

Comment: does not seem to work for me... cannot resolve method